# How to identify if an app is installed on iPhone from Windows PC?

Tags: ios, applications, windows, development

I am trying to identify programatically from computer if a particular app is installed in my iphone, once the iphone is connected to the computer( Windows OS).

How to proceed with this?

Comment: @Buscar웃 That would show up with the `.ipa` in your computer's iTunes library, and this is on Windows anyway.

Comment: thanks. But, i am not able to find the `.ipa` file in iTunes Library. Any reasons?

Comment: I was replying to Buscar who said (although his comment is now deleted) that you could use Spotlight, the Mac way of searching for files. If you aren't syncing your iPhone to your PC (and have been just downloading apps from the App Store on your phone), then you probably don't have it in your library. You would probably need a tool like [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) to do this, but I'm not experienced enough to know how it works. If you can set iExplorer up to automatically mount the iPhone's app directory, then you could probably detect it with a `.bat` script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after these many days, I found the answer myself. I just extended Manzana framework to support AMDeviceLookupApplications method as well. That worked